# How to pass NULL Value to Stored Procedure Through C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have multiple textboxes and I want to allow the user to leave some empty 
instead of giving the error

> SqlParameterCollection only accepts non-null SqlParameter type
>   objects.

What I use for inserting data  that is in Data_Access_Layer Class

```
public void ExecuteCommand(string Data, SqlParameter[] param)
    {
        SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand();
        sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        sqlcmd.CommandText = Data;
        sqlcmd.Connection = sqlconnection;


        if (param != null)
        {

            sqlcmd.Parameters.AddRange(param);
        }
```

The Main form Code:

```
namespace M_Weight_System.Presentation_Layer
{
    public partial class Main : Form
    {
        Bussiness_Layer.Cls_Data dta = new Bussiness_Layer.Cls_Data();
        public Main()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void bSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
              dta.Add_Data(tId.Text, tNumber.Text, tClient.Text, tDriver.Text, Convert.ToInt32(tFirst.Text), Convert.ToInt32(tSecond.Text), Convert.ToInt32(rt2.Text), tDate1.Text,tCity.Text, tType.Text,tDate2.Text);
                MessageBox.Show("Success");
                bEdit.Enabled = true;
                NewToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = true;
                PrintToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Problem !");
            }
        }

        private void bEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                dta.Update_Data(tId.Text, tNumber.Text, tClient.Text, tDriver.Text, Convert.ToInt32(tFirst.Text), Convert.ToInt32(tSecond.Text), Convert.ToInt32(rt2.Text), tDate1.Text, tCity.Text, tType.Text, tDate2.Text);
                MessageBox.Show("Success");

            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Problem !");
            }

        }
        }
}
```

Comment: `string.Empty`, `null`, and [`DbNull.Value`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.value(v=vs.110).aspx) are three different values. You probably want to add `DbNull.Value` to `param` if your textbox is empty.

Comment: You need to post your code where you create and set the `.Value` members of the `SqlParameter` objects.

Comment: Also, you need to wrap your `SqlCommand` in a `using` or `try/finally` block to ensure it's correctly disposed.

Comment: I'm new to databases , can you tell me where to put DbNull.Value @DourHighArch

Comment: I edited the article with the code @Dai

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can try this `command.Parameters.Add("@param", DBNull.Value);` or you can Set the defaults to NULL in the proc and you don't have to explicitly pass NULL to a proc.

```
CREATE PROC ..dbo.Proc ( @param1 int =NULL, @param2 varchar(40) = NULL ...)
```

Also, if you have to send NULL from your app you would use DBNull.Value

Comment: Avoid `AddWithValue`! Use `.Add( ... ).Value = value;` instead. https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use

```
sqlcmd.Parameters.AddRange(param == null ? (object)DBNull.Value : param);
```

Comment: it gives me "cannot convert from 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter[]' "

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'object' to 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter[]' M Weight System C:\Users\Mohamed\source\repos\M Weight System\M Weight System\Data Access Layer\DataAcessLayer.cs 69 Active